# Does the Swift toolchain eliminate code that is never called?

Tags: ios, swift, compilation, release

If I create an Xcode project with the iOS Single View Application template and choose Swift for the language, will the compiler exclude from the release build (binary) functions that never get called?

I'm wondering because I want to include a third-party library that has a lot of superfluous classes & functions, and I want to keep my app small & fast.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with comments, it is unlikely to impact performance in any significant way even if it was included...

Xcode 6 uses Apple LLVM Compiler Version 6.1, depending on how closely related it is to LLVM Developer Group's version the optimization feature is available http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html with options such as -dce: Dead Code Elimination, -adce: Aggressive Dead Code Elimination.

One way to know for sure what is included is checking the assembly output using -emit-assembly option in the swift compiler and review the output, or opening the binary in a disassembler such as Hopper ( http://www.hopperapp.com/download.html )